# Modifying DevExpress GridControl expand button

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am new to DevExpress and I couldn't find a solution to modify the plus sign on nested gridviews.
Since **some of my users** have tablets they want to expand rows by touching the plus sign. However they are having hard times to touch exactly on the plus sign.
Is there any way to modify it to make it larger?

[image: DevExpress GridControl]

Changing size of the sign or changing the image completely is pretty fine for me.

Your ideas are welcome.

Comment: How about clicking on the row = expanding? or maybe double click

Comment: That is an alternative solution which I can use only in some forms. In other grids, touching enables editing cells. In that case I need that plus sign.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through below reference links, These will provide you more details regarding your desired functionality:

**To modifying [Group Expand Button](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument550):**

[How to display an image in a group row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18890)
[GridView.CustomDrawGroupRow Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawGroupRowtopic)
[How to get skin's '+' icon for Custom Draw Group Rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q98688)

---

**In case of Mater-Details:**

For increasing the size of the Expand/collapse button:
[Enlarge Exapnd/Collapse button of master detail view in xtragrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q359829)
[master detail expand button size](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q396296)

> If you want to change GridView's expand\collapse icon then you can
>   change it by modifying an image of the Grid | PlusMinusEx skin
>   element. Here is a code snippet illustrating how to replace the image
>   with your custom one in a currently applied skin.

```
Skin skin = GridSkins.GetSkin(DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default);
SkinElement element = skin[GridSkins.SkinPlusMinusEx];
element.Image.SetImage(GetNewImage(), Color.Magenta);
LookAndFeelHelper.ForceDefaultLookAndFeelChanged();
```

> You can also paint the expand/collapse button on the CustomDrawCell
>   event handler.  Please see the [How to paint the master row's expand
>   buttons within the CustomDrawCell event](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2868.aspx) in exactly the same manner
>   as the XtraGrid does KB article for more information.

**References:**
[Draw custom expand/collapse button in GridView Row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T303715)
[Custom Draw +/- button for Master Detail GridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q90333)
[Grid - How to change the master-detail expand button](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T174059)
[XtraGrid:Adding a button to a cell that will allow cell data to expand - collapse.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q290698)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,  you could use the TouchUIMode feature which make thing bigger and easier to use in a touch enabled environment.  See this page :

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsWindowsFormsSettings_TouchUIModetopic

Edit : there is also a touch optimized skin which you can see in this blog post :
https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2011/12/29/build-for-beautiful-with-dxv2-metro-inspired-winforms-apps.aspx